# Creating a native background application using ndk

Tags: android-ndk, background-process

How to create more than 1 background applications in a single Android application using Android NDK ?

Need help in creating few background applications using NDK. My C application makes use of few standalone applications which run in the background (as services on windows). So my question is how can I create these standalone applications on Andriod platform?

I'm aware that these have to be services in Android applications, but services are Java code & NDK doesn't support C services & all my application code is in C. So how can I port these standalone applications onto Android along with my main application which uses these standalone helper applications. Should they be made separate libraries ?

If they are made separate libraries, then how can I ensure that they keep running in the background? I'm not sure, so any guidance will be very helpful. I don't want to root the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is very different from Windows, porting Windows services may be a significant challenge.

First of all, the IPC protocols are not the same, therefore you may need modifications to simply have your code compile.

The second issue is the background execution model of Android. On the newer versions, since Marshmallow, Google is improving the battery life by proactively killing all background services.

So, if you depend on these processes to be running always, you must keep your app in the foreground.

This said, you can build and run a command line executable for Android without wrapping it into an Android (Java) application or Service.

You can run them from the android shell (at least for testing), or use **Runtime.exec()** from Java. If you root the device, you can even start these executables on boot from **init.rc**, just as if it were a regular Linux box.

Comment: We can't root the device & that option is completely ruled out for us. how should I be using Runtime.exec() to kick start the helper applications, should it be from our JNI MainActivity file in the init method or in some-other way. Also, can we use the same technique if our application is not running on a dedicate device and if it runs as just another application.

Comment: You can use **Runtime.exec()** from anywhere in your Java code, you don't need JNI for that. If you use a NativeActivity (written in C++) and prefer to work with it, you have **execv()** and others in **unistd.h** in Android NDK. Note that both ways what you start is not an 'application' in Android parlance, but a 'process' - just as on Linux. It will run under the user of your **app**, and have same user-related permissions. The difference is that Android system has the 'right to kill' any user process. Some watchdogs may help. And keep all important data in persistent storage.

Comment: Ahh got it, so they will all be processes which are part of the main application.
Also, If we use JNI along with our native code, can we make the helper-applications (the processes in Android) as individual libraries and wrap each library in their respective services and instantiate those services from our main application or JNI ? so that they will be running as services (prefered in Android). Is this a correct approach ? Can those services be killed by Android System ?

Comment: There is no advantage in wrapping a daemon as Android Service. They are subject to kill just the same. Maybe, a Service is even worse. At any rate, if you don't need your background executable to handle the lifecycle of an Android Service, don't impose this on your 'applications'.

Comment: Thanks again for your time Alex, requesting another clarification. As these processes are subject to kill by Android OS, I need to maintain a watchdog (as you suggested earlier) to track these processes. since this watchdog will also be another process it is also susceptible to be killed by Android OS. **(1)** Is there no way to have at-least a single process that would not be killed by Android OS. **(2)** You mentioned 'Maybe, a Service is even worse' is it because it adds service overhead and the same can be accomplished with **Runtime.exec()**.

Comment: 1. Only system processes are exempt from being easy pray for the the memory manager. Note that on Android, the kernel performs no paging. The process either holds physical memory, or [gets killed](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle).

Comment: 2. Why and when a Service may become a legitimate target to be killed, is described in the [Project Lifescycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle) doc. The system expects certain cooperation from a Service, which may not be easy to add for a ported process. With a simple Posix process, you are at least not violating the rules.